# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.ModelMap

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I create a simple webapp using tomcat 6, spring 2.5.6 and maven.

The problem is when I boot up tomcat, I am getting the following errors:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/ModelMap
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.ModelMap
```

The ModelMap class does exist in `spring-2.5.6.jar` and `spring-context-2.5.6.jar`, I also have some other spring jars. All of them are being deployed to tomcat correctly, when I check the application WEB-INF (deployed to tomcat) I found all those jars there!

I have only one @Controller that has a `@RequestMapping("/home.htm") showForm(ModelMap model)` method.
My applicationContext is quite simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
              http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
              http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

<context:component-scan base-package="org.myapp"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Sorry, the applicationContext was not pasted correctly, here're the missing beans:

<context:component-scan base-package="org.islamweb"/>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

Comment: You can use the `edit` link to update the question.

Comment: Using the spring jar with everything in it is discouraged, and in fact not available with the 3.0.x release. So, I recommend you explicitly name the spring components that you need in your maven dependencies. (Typically, web-mvc, and one of the data access libs. core, beans, context, web are included as transitive dependencies of web-mvc, but it does no harm to include these explicitly as well.)

Answer (score 2):

`spring-2.5.6.jar` is the JAR that contains all of the spring framework. If you use that JAR, you should not use any of the other JARs like `spring-context-2.5.6.jar`. These smaller JARs are there if you want to pick ands choose the bits of Spring that you need.

It's possible that the classloader is getting confused between the duplicate copies of the classes between the JARs. Take out all of the Spring JARs except for `spring-2.5.6.jar`, and see if that makes a difference.