# Spring tutorial noClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, noclassdeffounderror

I am following the Spring tutorial located  [here](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) (link is to chapter 1, but I'm currently on chapter 2, part 2.2). I have about 2 years experience with Java from college, but I have never done anything with Spring before, which is why I thought a step by step tutorial would be helpful.

The problem is, the tutorial provides a link to download all the necessary jar files, but the link now points to the [spring projects page](http://spring.io/projects). The "Spring Framework" link there seems to require you to download it from GitHub, which I did, but there doesn't seem to be any jar files in this download. So whenever the tutorial said to use a certain jar file, I just Googled it and found it somewhere else, and everything seemed to work fine.

So here is the problem: on step 2.2 "Improve the controller" I have followed the instructions and get to the part that says

> "We rerun our 'tests' target and the test passes"

but as you might have guessed, it did not work for me, giving the following error:

```
[junit] ------------- Standard Error -----------------
[junit] May 13, 2014 8:40:40 AM springapp.web.HelloController handleRequest
[junit] INFO: Returning hello view with Tue May 13 08:40:40 BST 2014
[junit] ------------- ---------------- ---------------
[junit] Testcase: testHandleRequestView(springapp.web.HelloControllerTests):
    Caused an ERROR
[junit] org/springframework/ui/ModelMap
[junit] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/ModelMap
[junit]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.getModelMap(Mode
lAndView.java:205)
[junit]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.addObject(ModelA
ndView.java:227)
[junit]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.<init>(ModelAndV
iew.java:127)
[junit]     at springapp.web.HelloController.handleRequest(HelloController.j
ava:26)
[junit]     at springapp.web.HelloControllerTests.testHandleRequestView(Hell
oControllerTests.java:13)
[junit] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.
ModelMap
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Test springapp.web.HelloControllerTests FAILED
BUILD FAILED
```

I have Googled NoClassDefFoundError, and one of the causes seems to be missing jar files. I think that is the case here, since I found them all through Google.

So my question is, am I correct in assuming that this is the problem, and if so does anyone know what jar file I am missing and where to find it? Or has anyone completed this tutorial before and can provide me with these jars?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: These are the jars that i currently have in war/WEB-INF/lib, they have all been added to the build path:

```
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar  
servlet-api.jar  
junit-4.11.jar  
jstl.jar  
standard.jar  
spring-webmvc.jar  
spring.jar
```

Comment: The tutorial you are following is pretty old!!! I suggest you check out the tutorial here https://spring.io/guides/

Comment: Yes, it is pretty old, but it was the first one that I found with "step-by-step" in the title, so I thought it would be perfect. I didn't realize how old it was until I was on chapter 2! Anyway, I'll check out the tutorials you linked to, hopefully they will be more useful.

Comment: That's a good idea. If you have any problems, SO is always here to help :)

Comment: In response to Imran: 1) I have the jars in the Web-Inf\lib folder, I have edited my question with all the jars in there 2) I'm not sure what you mean by "Deployment Assembly", do you mean add to build path?  The answer in the question that you linked to suggests that there might be a conflict between duplicate classes in the jar files, so I removed spring-webmvc.jar and got some errors in eclipse, and spring.jar which gave me the same NoClassDefFoundError error. Also, I am not using maven as the tutorial does not mention it at all

Comment: You probably should have added the comment to the specific answer :)

Comment: Good idea, just did that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

IN Dynamic web project you need to make sure two things regarding this  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:`  error

1. Place all requires Jar in Web-Inf\lib folder
2. Add these jars reference in Deployment Assembly as well.
   [image]

Right now you are missing Jar that is required by Spring at run-time.. Please see details here

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.ModelMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753464/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-ui-modelmap)

There may be the other reason if you are using maven etc..

This error `org/springframework/ui/ModelMap` means that class not found by server at load time.. Its not compilation issue, infact run-time issue..

Comment: 1) I have the jars in the Web-Inf\lib folder, I have edited my question with all the jars in there 2) I'm not sure what you mean by "Deployment Assembly", do you mean add to build path? The answer in the question that you linked to suggests that there might be a conflict between duplicate classes in the jar files, so I removed spring-webmvc.jar and got some errors in eclipse, and spring.jar which gave me the same NoClassDefFoundError error. Also, I am not using maven as the tutorial does not mention it at all

Comment: Right click of project properties in eclipse you got the tab of "Deployment Assembly"

Comment: I right click and went to Properties, but "Deployment Assembly" isn't there

Comment: I've added screenshots please see it.... ALso see..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753464/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-ui-modelmap

Comment: Here is what I see in properties: http://s14.postimg.org/v5j5ohuch/properties.png

Comment: I think it is a regular java project. The tutorial didn't say to create web project